# Does an irreducible Markov chain have exactly one equivalence class?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, irreducible-representation

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of equivalence classes and irreducibility of Markov chains.

Consider this simple MC where States A and B communicate ($ A \leftrightarrow B $) and States C and D can also communicate ($ C \leftrightarrow D $), but States A and C can only move one way ($ A \rightarrow C $). So we get two equivalence classes, allowing us to reduce the Markov chain to the one on the right, which shows $ \text{Class 1} \rightarrow \text{Class 2} $:

[image]

Now that we have reduced this Markov chain, can we say that it is irreducible, and if so, why does this clearly have more than one equivalence class when supposedly "All irreducible Markov chains have exactly one equivalence class"?

Comment: Notice that writing the Markov chain in terms of its equivalence classes does NOT change the dynamics whatsoever, your chain is still the chain with states A,B,C,D. 

Irreducibility, however, is a dynamical property and does not depend on the representation used. A Markov chain is irreducible if all states intercommunication, meaning that you can go from any state to any other state (possibly in multiple steps)! This is not the case here: you can go from A to C but never from C to A. Hence, the provided Markov chain is not irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

A finite state space Markov-Chain is (by definition) irreducible if the associated graph is strongly connected (we can move from any state to any other).
The reduced Markov-Chain on the right is not strongly connected (you can not go from 2 to 1).

Comment: So, just because we have "reduced" the Markov chain on the left to become the one on the right, it doesn't mean that it becomes "irreducible"?